# Generating 3D data with cube as a decision surface

Tags: r, neural-network

I am new to using r program. I have a task to use r to create a function to simulate standard normal distribution containing 500 observations and three variables, x,y,& z.
I am to use cube as a decision surface to categorize observations based on whether they fell within or outside the cube.

Below is my code. I am able to plot the 3D data, but I am not sure of how to categorize the datasets into two classes.

```
library(scatterplot3d)
set.seed (1234)
nObs <- 500
x <- matrix (rnorm (1.25*nObs), ncol =2)
y <- matrix (rnorm (1.25*nObs), ncol =2)
z <- matrix (rnorm (1.25*nObs), ncol =2)


mSample <- function(nObs,x,y,z){
x1 <- rnorm(1,x)
x1[y==1,] <- x[y==1,] + 1
mSample <- as_tibble(rbind(mvnfast::rmvn(x,y = y1,z = z1), mvnfast::rmvn(x,y =  y1,z = z1)))
mSample[1:x1, 1.25] <- 0
mSample[(x1 + 1):(x1 + 1), 1.25] <- 1
mSample <- mSample[sample(nrow(mSample)), ]
colnames(mSample <- c("x", "y", "class"))
mSample
}

spl <- scatterplot3d(x,y,z)
spl <- scatterplot3d(x,y,z,pch=16,highlight.3d=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question to this recently. Basically, to know if a given point is inside or outside of a cube, first you need to know the length of the cube.

Then, simply iterate over all the points (nObs) and do an if statement

```
if (x > -cubeLength ** x < cubeLength && y > -cubeLength ** y < cubeLength && z > -cubeLength ** z < cubeLength) {
classify positive
}
else {
classify negative
}
```